# when I creates folder in sharepoint 2013 through cmis object it returns error unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint-2013, cmis, cmis-workbench

Here is the code creating folder:

```
Folder rootFolder = session.getRootFolder();
  System.out.println("Root Folder Name: "+rootFolder.getName());
  System.out.println("Root Folder Id: "+rootFolder.getId());

  Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
 \\here mention the property 

  props.put("cmis:objectTypeId", "cmis:folder");

  props.put("cmis:name","folder1");
  \\creating folder 

  Folder someFolder = rootFolder.createFolder(props);

  System.out.println("Folder created!");

  System.out.println("id:" + someFolder.getId());

  System.out.println("name:" + someFolder.getName());
```

It returns error unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

add one more Sessionparameter

parameter.put(SessionParameter.AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER_CLASS, CmisBindingFactory.NTLM_AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER);